# proc sgpanel reg only on one modality of group

Tags: sas

I have some computing problem with SAS 9.2.

Here is my code:

```
data test;
set sashelp.cars;
WHERE Make in ('Acura', 'Audi');
run

proc sgpanel data=test;
panelby origin;
reg y=Weight x=Length/group=Make;
run;
```

The regression option is applied on the 2 modalities of the variable Make.
Is it possible to allpy it only one one of them? For instance, only on the Make 'Audi'?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: can you provide some sample data?

Comment: the sample data is in sas => it is called cars. You can see it in the Library sashelp.

Answer (score 0):

Just make two separate plots with `sgplot`.

```
/* regression plot for the one you need the regression */
proc sgplot data=sashelp.cars;
WHERE Make eq 'Audi';
reg y=Weight x=Length/group=Make;
run;

/* scatter plot for the one you need no regression */
proc sgplot data=sashelp.cars;
WHERE Make eq 'Acura';
scatter y=Weight x=Length/group=Make;
run;
```

Also not I integrated the selection in the graphical procedure.